# expanding dimensions and replicating data in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor `input` of size BxHxWx3 and another tensor `params` of size Bx3. here is B is the batch size. I want to `params` into a tensor of size BxHxWx3? So that I can multiply the two tensors. Any suggestions on how should I go about this? (At a high level, what i want to do is multiply each pixel in a set of images by a value defined for each channel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. To answer your first question**

You could use a combination of `tf.expand_dims`, `tf.tile`:

```
input_shape = tf.shape(input)
mod_params = params.expand_dims(1) # shape is [Bx1x3]
mod_params = mod_params.expand_dims(2) # shape is [Bx1x1x3]
mod_params = tf.tile( \
                mod_params, \
                [1, input_shape[1], input_shape[2], 1] \
             ) # shape is [BxHxWx3]
```

**2. To perform your end result, ...**

... you could perform

```
ret = tf.multiply(input, mod_params)
```

... or, you also could use the broadcasting ability of tensorflow (with the help of `tf.transpose`)

```
ret = tf.multiply(
         tf.transpose(input, perm=[2,1,0,3]), \
         params \
      ) # shape: [WxHxBx3]
ret = tf.transpose(ret, perm=[2,1,0,3]) # shape: [BxHxWx3]
```

Comment: the answer to the first question seems promising. I tried it, but the tile method gives an error, like so: `List of Tensors when single Tensor expected`

Comment: I think the `tf.constant` wrapping in the tiling specifications was causing the error. Removing it should make it work. Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Dont tile, Use `broadcasting` : `T*tf.reshape(params, [-1,1, 1, tf.shape(n_params)[1]])`

```
T = tf.random_normal((5,2,3,3))
params = tf.random_normal((5,3))

out = T*tf.reshape(params, [-1,1, 1, tf.shape(n_params)[1]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(out).shape)
   #(5, 2, 3, 3)
```